# Conectar clase hijo y padre con los inputs

Tags: java, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Se pide una tabla de multiplicar hasta el número 10 en la clase hijo y que después lo vuelva a leer el buffer, pongo código:

```
       int i = 0;
       int numero;
       int resultado;
       //leemos de teclado
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                       //introducimos por teclado 
                       line = reader.readLine();
                       //cambiamos el int al String
                       numero = Integer.parseInt(line);
       //inicializamos bucle hasta 10.                
       while (i<=10){
       resultado = numero *i;
           System.out.println("El resultado es: "+numero + " X " + i +" = " + resultado);
           // la variable aumenta hasta 10
          
       i++;
       line = reader.readLine();
       }
```

**Me gustaría conectar la clase padre con la hijo para que diera 10 inputs y que estos imprimieran la tabla del 1...10**
Dejo el código por aquí:

```
            line = entradaPadre.readLine();
            
                for (int i=1; contador<10; contador++){
                    numero = Integer.parseInt(line);
                    salidaHijo.println(line);
                    salidaHijo.flush();
                    System.out.println("mensaje enviado al proceso hijo");
                    line = entradaHijo.readLine();
                    System.out.println(line);
                    line = entradaPadre.readLine();    
                    
                }
                System.out.println("Proceso finalizado");
```

[image: Esta es la imagen del error:]

Este es el segundo día que llevo con esto, y aunque he solucionado varias cosas no entiendo donde está el fallo. He buscado por internet y nada.
Espero que me podáis ayudar, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: No es que me dé un error, es que debería imprimir la tabla hasta el 10, dando error cuando tecleemos 11. Pero cuando tecleo por ejemplo 5 el resultado que me da es 0. Como pone en la imagen. Lo que busco es que me imprima toda la tabla conectandosé con el proceso hijo.

Comment: no sobra un readline dentro del while?

Comment: El problema es el siguiente: en el proceso hijo se pide hacer una tabla de multiplicar con el while, cuando meto el readline dentro del while no me deja hacer bien la tabla de multiplicar. Si lo quito si me deja. Por otro lado en la clase padre: no me imprime la tabla de multiplicar, me multiplica por 0 continuamente.

Comment: no entiendo tu logica.. para que queres un readline dentro del while??? pensalo como si fueran personas.. me pedis que escriba la tabla de multiplicar, pero escribo un numero, y depues me quedo esperando que cosa??? y al padre, en que momento le devolves algo?

Comment: Quiero un redline dentro del while porque busco que se vuelva a inicializar la tabla de multiplicar hasta el numero 10 otra vez. En la clase padre se le devuelve algo después de  System.out.println(line); se da esto
                    line = entradaPadre.readLine(); No sé si es correcto

Comment: PEro estas dentro del while, donde se supone queres mostrar la tabla de multiplicar! si queres que vuelva a mostrar la tabla, no deberia haber un proceso mostrar tabla, que solo se dedique a eso.. y si queres que papa te hable, una vez que terminas eso le pedis que te hable??? si esta adentro del while, no termina de mostrar la tabla y ya esta esperando que le hablen para que le digan que cosa??? usa el boton [edit] y pone cual es el resultado que esperas que te de ese codigo...

Comment: lo edité, no se si así queda mas claro.

Comment: si clarisimo.. no se tanto de java como para hacer procesos en paralelo.. pero la logica del codigo esta mal... fijate que no hace lo que vos decis que tiene que hacer.. si tengo que imprimir toda la tabla del 0, entonces papa deberia recibir 10 inputs antes de decirle a hijo que pase al siguiente.. no es cierto?? y eso, no esta pasando... proba hacer todo este proceso para la tabla del 0.. y despues avanza....

Comment: los inputs desde donde los tiene que recibir? desde padre? no te sigo muy bien. Pero me estás ayudando! gracias :D

Comment: hacelo en papel.. dos columnas.. papa, hijo.. y anda escribiendo en cada columna que envia.. vas a ver que no es como esta en tu codigo.. cada vez que uno envia algo, uno escribe y el otro lee... escribi todas las lineas que tienen que salir...

Comment: Gracias! pero no lo veo, pero me sirvió.

Comment: ok.. cuando lo hagas en papel y lo pases a codigo, modifica la pregunta.. y si no te sale, pongo una respuesta para ver si entendes mejor...

Comment: Lo he estado mirando, pero no sé como generar inputs desde padre para hijo, este los imprime pero no como yo lo pido.

Comment: Fijate, que entonces tu problema es ese.. como comunicar un padre y un hijo.. esa deberia ser tu pregunta en este momento.. los problemas tenes que mirarlos de a uno.. primero tenes que poder hacer que hablen.. despues te preocupas por el resto... yo que vos, encaro esa pregunta primero.. tengo padre e hijo.. quiero que padre le mande a hijo algo.. e hijo lo recibe y lo imprime.. como hago eso???

Comment: Muchas gracias! me lo estas haciendo ver un poco mejor. Se que se conectan a traves de entradaHijo.readLine y entradaPadre.readline, el problema es con el bucle las 10 veces ya está impreso, sin embargo cuando introduzco el número este no lo sustituye sino que lo impreme del 1...10 tal y como yo quiero, pero sin sustituirlo y nos correcto del todo. Me gustaría que lo imprimiese de golpe.

Comment: ya dí con la solución! gracias :D

Comment: agregala en la seccion respuesta, bien explicado cual era el problema y cual la solucion! despues de 24 hs, podes aceptarla...